# Content Component in Native Base React is not rendering

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, native-base

I desigining react native UI using Native base 
 library(http://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#anatomy-headref). I am following their most basic example(the skeleton), but the Content Component is not showing up at all. Given that Most of the subcomponentes are depended on this, I am stuck on this library. I could render Grid which make sthis problem more weird for me. I am using there baseline example give in their documentation
http://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#anatomy-headref ,only header is rendering.

```
 import {Container,Header, Title, Button, Icon,Text} from 'native-base'; 
 //Include Nativebase required components
 import React from 'react';
  import {  StatusBar, StyleSheet ,View} from 'react-native'; //Most of the 
   react native components can be found in NativeBase
  import { Font } from 'expo'; //to include font from expo.

   // load up the child components 
  import BodyComponent from './body_container';


  export default class ContainerApp extends React.Component {
  //checking state for if font is loaded or not.
  state = {
   fontLoaded: false,
 };

 async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
     'Roboto_medium': require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf'),
  });
     //Setting the state to true when font is loaded.
     this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
   }



  render() {
      return (

      this.state.fontLoaded && (
        <BodyComponent /> 
      )

    );
   }
 }
```

body component

```
        export default class BodyComponent extends React.Component {
            constructor(props){
                super(props);

            }
            render(){
                return(
                <Container>
                    <Header>
                    <Left>
                        <Button transparent>
                        <Icon name='menu' />
                        </Button>
                    </Left>
                    <Body>
                        <Title>Header</Title>
                    </Body>
                    <Right />
                    </Header>   


                    <Content>
                        <Text>
                            This is Content Section
                        </Text>
                    </Content>

                </Container>

                )

            }
        }
```

the ui showing up like (Pixel XL android)
[The UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9lZw.png)

I created repo  https://github.com/abdullah2891/react_native_practice

Comment: In `main_view.js` wrap `<ContainerApp>` inside `<Container/>` instead of `<View/>`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the version of native base is changed. So I revert it and convert `native-base: ^2.15.2`